# How do I override a template-tag for the "pinax" application in Django?

Tags: django, pinax

Unfortunately for me, the "pinax" application for Django does not seem to have stayed up with the times – in one specific way:  the **shorttimesince** template-tag still refers to the `tzinfo` object which has been deprecated.

The message is this:

```
 django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'pinax.templatetags.templatetags.shorttimesince_tag': No module named 'django.utils.tzinfo'
```

In my project, I have a `overrides/pinax/templatetags` directory which contains both `__init__.py` and `shorttimesince_tag.py` which contains the updated code. But it does not seem to be referenced. *(And I think that, after studying this problem, I see why not.)*

I need to be able to override a templatetag that is defined in a **third-party** application.  Does Django actually *know* where a templatetag is defined? Please guide me to a swift and appropriate solution.

Pardon me, community ... I am very befuddled by all of this, and writing this while "still befuddled."

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to have left this question sitting around unanswered for so long ... here is what I finally (and, successfully) decided to do.

I realized that the "pinax" library application appears to no longer be maintained, even though there is really (so far ...) only this one slight problem with it.  So, I moved the package into my own project and removed it from the library (and from `requirements.txt` ...).  After first branching and git-committing the change which moved it, I then made the very-trivial change to fix the problem with `shorttimesince_tag.py` and committed that, then merged my branch into the mainline.  From now on, "pinax" has officially become "part of my project."

"It's really too bad" when really-great packages like "pinax" come to be abandoned, but every now and again it happens, I suppose . . . we are all volunteers.